# MVC Mini Profiler - LINQ overhead

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, mvc-mini-profiler

I'm using MVC Mini Profiler and I'm trying to measure the impact the LINQ to SQL portion of the query (generating the expression tree, the actual SQL command, etc) versus the time that was spent on the database side.

I see an "aggregate duration of all queries in this step (excludes children)". Does this include the LINQ to SQL portion and the database call, or only the database portion? When clicking on the "sql" link to see the list of queries that were ran I see a query duration. Again, does this include the LINQ portion or just the database side?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SQL timings are **just** the SQL - since that is coming from the wrapped ADO.NET connection, and knows very little about the caller. To get detailed timings for that (to measure the overheads), wrap the code you are interested in:

```
using(profiler.Step("Get orders")) {
    orders = db.{some query}.ToList();
}
```

Now you have a timing for the unit of code, and *inside* that timing, the SQL timings that correspond to it. So if the "Get orders" code took 100ms, and the SQL took 40ms, then you have 60ms of overheads.

Things to reduce overhead:

- try precompiling the query
- try switching to `ExecuteQuery<T>`, so there **is** no expression tree to parse

From experience, though, you'll probably find that *most* of those overheads come from "materialization" (i.e. turning the rows from the database into objects), especially in a high throughput scenario. We found the only way to shed that overhead was to use dapper-dot-net as a replacement to `ExecuteQuery<T>` (it has an intentionally similar API). With that, we have virtually no overheads between the timings for "Get orders", and the timings for the SQL in that block.

Comment: Thanks Marc. Yes, on one particular page I have 9 sql queries totaling about 5ms, rendering logic about 5.5ms, the rest is LINQ2SQL overhead of about 165ms; rather unacceptable imo. I considered ExecuteQuery/Dapper/Massive/etc. The problem with all these is that I would need to go back to string SQLs. From what I found the fastest library that still allows me to stay in LINQ land seems to be BLToolkit. I'll need to look more into it.

Comment: @pbz you might want to try the precompiled-query first; that removes the expression-tree parsing step, etc, but you still have the materialization overhead. You might also try disabling change tracking and the identity manager, if possible.

Comment: I'll have run some tests and see if the compiled queries make a significant difference (tracking is disabled). Thanks.

Comment: @pbz to set expectation: for us, it *helped*, but wasn't the significant part. Which is why we went away and wrote dapper ;p Certainly worth trying, though, so you have the most accurate numbers

Comment: FWIW for a number of queries the overhead in my tests is as follows: 0.32ms for Dapper, 0.47ms for BLToolkit, 1ms for compiled LINQ2SQL (surprise surprise), 12.6ms for non-compiled LINQ2SQL. The database queries took on average 1.6ms. I made sure all 3 generated identical SQL queries.

Comment: With compiled BLToolkit LINQ queries the overhead is 0.36ms so almost the same as Dapper.

Comment: @pbz thanks for the extra numbers - good to know. The overhead for L2S is indeed very noticeable, but in most cases it very noticeably out-performs both EF and NH. I dread to think what they would have taken!